# Increament Badge after termination or if app is not running

Tags: objective-c

How can i update the "badge" count if app is terminated/Not running on forground and background?Please help me to update the badge count and also increamnet it if already badge count is greater than "0"

Answer (score 0):

I think that part should be handled from the backend, you must have non opened notification count stored at the backend. then the payload of the notification should be something like :

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "You got your emails.",
        "badge" : 9,
        "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
    },
    "acme1" : "bar",
    "acme2" : 42
}
```

Here, the system will handle automatically the badge count and change it.

For better clarification about notification see [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html)